# Converting MP3 to AAC and outputting to stdout

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, aac, audio-conversion

```
ffmpeg.exe -i s.mp3 -f aac -
```

This is the command I run but it doesn't recognize the format AAC.

```
Requested output format 'aac' is not a suitable output format pipe:: 
Invalid argument
```

However when I run:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i s.mp3 -f ogg -
```

This works.

Also, outputting to a file like this works:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i s.mp3 o.aac
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you run this command:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i s.mp3 o.aac
```

you may notice the following line in the output:

```
Output #0, adts, to 'o.aac':
```

Here, `ffmpeg` is telling you that it is using the format called `adts` to generate an .aac file. Use `-f adts` instead of `-f aac`:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i s.mp3 -f adts -
```